# C # Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#, sql

Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

I have a following function which throws the above error. I am handling all nulls in  my database and in the C# code.
So where is it getting this error?

I can see the error in the catch block. But i am not understanding which line in the following create() getting the error.

```
    private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dt.Rows.Clear();
            SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(mysql.CON.ConnectionString);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select EMP_EMPLOYEES.NAME,EMP_EMPLOYEES.JOBNAME,EMP_EMPLOYEES.FIA,EMP_EMPLOYEES.DRAGA,EMP_EMPLOYEES.SALARY ,EMP_HASM_DET.GZA,EMP_EMPLOYEES.NAQLBADAL,EMP_EMPLOYEES.JOBBADALAT ,BLADIAINFO.MA3ESHA ,EMP_EMPLOYEES.DISSENT ,EMP_EMPLOYEES.SANDOK as'الصندوق' from  BLADIAINFO ,EMP_EMPLOYEES left join EMP_HASM_DET on EMP_HASM_DET.EMPID = EMP_EMPLOYEES.ID  left join EMP_MOKHALFAT_DET on EMP_MOKHALFAT_DET.EMPID = EMP_EMPLOYEES.ID  left join EMP_MOKHALFAT on EMP_MOKHALFAT.ID=EMP_MOKHALFAT_DET.MOKHALFAID left join EMP_HASMIAT on EMP_HASMIAT.ID=EMP_HASM_DET.HASMID   and EMP_EMPLOYEES.EMPTYPE = '" + cmbEMPTYPE.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ", CN);
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            ////////////
            dt.Columns.Add("Actual_salary", typeof(string));

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                int GZA = dr["GZA"] == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["GZA"]);
                dr["Actual_salary"] = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SALARY"]) - ((Convert.ToInt32(dr["SALARY"]) / 30) * GZA);

            }
            dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Try `int GZA=dr["GZA"] == DBNull.Value.Equals(dr["GZA"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["GZA"]);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check whether your column has null value or not before casting it to another type. As you are checking it with *null*, but `dr["GZA"]` won't be null, So you need to check it with `DBNull.Value`

Try this

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    int GZA = (dr["GZA"] == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["GZA"]);
    if (dr["SALARY"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        dr["Actual_salary"] = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SALARY"]) - ((Convert.ToInt32(dr["SALARY"]) / 30) * GZA);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `DBNull` instead of `DB.Null`?

Comment: @Tim yes I missed that. :)

Comment: may I know the reason of downvote? that may be helpful for me :)

Comment: Alas, SO doesn't enforce a comment/reason policy for downvotes.  I wish it did, as sometimes the person being downvoted could learn from the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this on one line:

```
int salary = reader["SALARY"] as int? ?? 0;

dr["Actual_salary"] = salary  - ((salary/30) * GZA);
```

You can put 0 or whatever value for a DBNull result.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static string MyToString(object o)
    {
        if (o == DBNull.Value || o == null)
            return "";

        return o.ToString();
    }
```

for converting to decimal:

```
spinHOInvAmt.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["HOInvAmount"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : dr["HOInvAmount"]);
```