# How to insert every cell in columns with datetime from ms excel to mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, excel, datetime

I'm programming in C# .net for about 1 month. Now I'm trying to write code in this language which imports data from MS excel (Office 365) to datagridview then to mysql database. In this case i have a table which i do it the sheet:

[Order_status table from MS Excel to DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD96e.png)

When i import the data to datagridview then i try to insert the data into mysql database. All code is in the below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ControlDataBase
{
    public partial class New_Tables : Form
    {
        public New_Tables()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Form1 frm1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xls;*.xml;*.xml;*.xlam;*.xla;*.xlw;*.xlr;", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
                    string FileName1 = ofd.FileName;

                    string excel = fi.FullName;

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;\"";
                    }

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 1.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
                    }
                    OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(StrConn);

                    OleDbDataAdapter dta5 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Order_status$]", oledbconn);
                    oledbconn.Open();

                    DataSet dsole5 = new DataSet();
                    dta5.Fill(dsole5, "Order_status$");
                    datagrdStatus_order.DataSource = dsole5.Tables["Order_status$"];

                    oledbconn.Close();

                    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=");
                    connection.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.ORDER_DESC = @ORDER_DESC AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", connection);

                    DateTime begin_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
                    DateTime end_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_DESC", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMBER_ORDER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", begin_date);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", end_date);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("The data are imported correctly");

                    loaddataalldatagridview();
                }
            }
        }

        private void loaddataalldatagridview()
        {
            frm1.loaddata5();
        }
    }
}
```

When i execute that code the i get the error at the line of code:

```
DateTime begin_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
```

which shows:

> System.InvalidCastException: "You cannot cast from the DBNull element to other types."

But it inserted most of the imported data but not all of them. I wanna import all of the data.

**What i've tried?**

1) I'm added to datetime objects just `.ToString();`

```
            for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.ORDER_DESC = @ORDER_DESC AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", connection);

                DateTime begin_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                DateTime end_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_DESC", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMBER_ORDER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", begin_date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", end_date);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

But it shows:

> System.FormatException: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

2) I was trying it by adding string to objects then converting to datetime:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.ORDER_DESC = @ORDER_DESC AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", connection);

                DateTime begin_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
                string MysqlFormatDate = begin_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                DateTime begin_date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(MysqlFormatDate);

                DateTime end_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
                string MysqlFormatDate2 = end_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                DateTime end_date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(MysqlFormatDate2);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_DESC", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMBER_ORDER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", begin_date2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", end_date2);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

But it didn't work too (it shew the error like in 1-st try).

3) I declared string object and convert to DateTime:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.ORDER_DESC = @ORDER_DESC AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", connection);

                string begin_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                string end_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_DESC", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMBER_ORDER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", begin_date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", end_date);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

But then it shew the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: "You cannot cast from the DBNull element
>   to other types."

I have no clue and idea how to solve it. I was searching for solution i haven't found it? Can someone please explain how to solve it? Any ideas? Thank you for any help and advice. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please checkt this question first which seems describe your problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075574/447156

Comment: Hi @SonerGönül. Thank you for comment. But i see only for type int32. Do you think that it will work for type datetime?

Comment: It seems that your value came as a `DBNull` from your database. Check it is `DBNull` first, if it is not, then you can call it's value and use it.

Comment: @Johnyblumer2012 your `for` loop starts with `i` = `0` so you might be getting the column header names in the first iteration and maybe thats why the error

Comment: @akg179 when firstly i created ms excel sheet (before modifying to drop down lists) and it worked everything for me. So i think that `i=0` in my loop can't cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Excel operations, the first and foremost thing to do is to include the Microsoft.Office Object Library reference to the project.

`using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

And try to convert the dateTime like this :

```
DateTime begin_Date= DateTime.ParseExact(row[8].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", cultureUS, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: Hi @Syafiqur. Really? Have i to convert datetime without declaring datagridview?

Comment: You have to declare the Excel into dataTable first, and then convert the dateTime. So the gridView can retireve the value of the dateTime

Comment: I'm afraid that your code line with datetime won't work.

Comment: Really? It worked for me tho. Try to convert with another converter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrdStatus_order.Rows)
{
    string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = ";
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.DESC_ORDER = @DESC_ORDER AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", row.Cells["ID_WORKER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", row.Cells["FNAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", row.Cells["LNAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESC_ORDER", row.Cells["DESC_ORDER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_NUMBER", row.Cells["ORDER_NUMBER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", row.Cells["NAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", row.Cells["PROJECT_NAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", row.Cells["AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", row.Cells["BEGIN_DATE"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", row.Cells["END_DATE"].Value);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```